# Determine the value of $k$ such that the points $A(4,-2,6)$, $B(0,1,0)$, $C(1,0,-5)$ and $D(1,k, -2)$ lie on the same plane.

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

$A(4,-2,6) \ ; \ B(0,1,0) \ ; \ C(1,0,-5) \ ; \ D(1,k, -2)$

if they lie on the same plane. How can i determine this?
How do you know that the points lie on the same plane?

Like do i check if they intersect? How would i do this?
(sorry for so many questions!)

Comment: Hint: Vectors lie on the same plane if and only if they are linearly dependent.

Comment: @cygorx That is only true of $3$ or more vectors

Comment: @TimRatigan, there are many ways to build off of that idea.

Comment: @cygorx I'm not disputing that, I'm disputing your claim.  $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are linearly independent _and_ lie in the same plane.

Comment: @cygorx what does "linearly dependent" mean?

Comment: @Jessica "Linearly dependent" means that you can express one vector as a linear combination of the others.  Or, equivalently, there exists more than one solution to the equation $\sum_i c_i\vec{v_i} = \vec{0}$ (where the $\vec{v_i}$ are your vectors)

Answer (score 1):

What is the volume of the solid $[A,B,C,D]$? The answer is

$$
\left((B-A) \times (C-A)\right) \cdot (D-A)
$$

Now $D$ will be in the plane if the volume is zero. So solve
$$
\left((B-A) \times (C-A)\right) \cdot D = \left((B-A) \times (C-A)\right) \cdot A$$
You can simplify this to
$$
\left(A\times B + B\times C+C\times A\right) \cdot D = (B\times C) \cdot A$$

Answer (score 0):

@ Jessica. Firstly, you have to check if the three points A,B,C do not lie on the same line, and they don't because their coordinates are linearly independent. In order to see this, you have to put A, B, C, in the same matrix and compute the determinant, as follows: 
$$\det \begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0 & 1 \\ 
-2 & 1  & 0 \\ 
 6 & 0 & -5 
\end{bmatrix} \neq 0
$$
now that you know this, considering a generic point $P=(x,y,z)$, the three vectors, namely $\overrightarrow{AP}$, $\overrightarrow{AC}$ and $\overrightarrow{AB}$ must be linearly dependent. In order to set this concept, you have to write the follow determinant
$$\det \begin{bmatrix}
x-4 & y-2 & z-6 \\ 
-3 & 2  & -11 \\ 
-4 & 3 & -6 
\end{bmatrix} = 0
$$
by a simple computation you'll obtain the cartesian equation of the plane, that is $\pi) 21x+26y-z-26$. (you can verify the correctness of the result by simply substituting each tern of coordinates in $\pi$. Doing this you must obtain an identity as indeed is). 
Now you're able to determine the value of the parameter $k$ such that $D \in \pi$. That $k$ is computed simply substituting the coordinates of the point $D$ inside the equation of $\pi$. You'll find as solution $k=\frac{7}{26}$

Comment: the answer in the book is 3/26

Comment: There must be a mistake somewhere but the method seems to me correct

Answer (score 0):

If we let $\overrightarrow{a}=\overrightarrow{BA}=<4,-3,6>$ and $\overrightarrow{b}=\overrightarrow{BC}=<1,-1,-5>$, then a normal vector to the plane containing A,B, and C is given by $\overrightarrow{n}=\overrightarrow{a}\times\overrightarrow{b}=<21,26,-1>$; so the plane has equation

$21(x-0)+26(y-1)-1(z-0)=0\;$ or $\;21x+26y-z=26$.

Substituting the coordinates of D gives $21+26k-2=26$, so $k=\frac{7}{26}$ as in the previous answer.